# eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]) always 0 on geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, rinkeby, geth-debugging

I want to deploy smart contract on rinkeby test network. I create account in Rinkeby test network.And connect with "Ethereum geth node".I successfully funded "https://faucet.rinkeby.io/". I also check balance in requesting account address on "https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/ce82bd5a2a5ea3582446ae117576278fee5dee3f".

But when I check on geth console with **eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])** so account balance is **0**.Also when I check **eth.accounts[4])** to **eth.accounts[7]** so it show value **3000000000000000000**. And "**eth.accounts[8]**" is my original funded balance **7500000000000000000**. " It is the request account address value.**eth.syncing**" is also **False**.

So My question is why **eth.accounts[0]** balance is **0** and other accounts value **3000000000000000000**? .Why eth.syncing is False?.While I connect ethereum node to rinkeby test-network last 15  hours??

Comment: Check if the last block with `eth.blockNumber` from geth console is close to the latest block on etherscan. If they are close then your node is synchronized. If your not has not synced check if you have peers `admin.peers`, restart your node.

Comment: Hi Ismael,thanks for comments. My **eth.blokNumber** is 0.It is not colose to latest block number.So it's mean get h is not synced.I also restart node.But my account balance is **zero**

Comment: Please tell me ass soon as,Why it is happen??

Comment: Well your node has not synced and it does not have peers. Perhaps is some problem with your network like a firewall blocking connections with other nodes, I used to have problems with my router NAT not helping to find nodes. You might try adding nodes manually from https://www.ethernodes.org/network/4/nodes.

Comment: Hi Ismael,I have deleted ethereum directory.I reconnect ethereum network.I run command to create new account in **rinkeby** network.I successfully create account with this address "
0x337e3e21cfdc1742d38a0ddb17981e8781e67476".So,check **eth.accounts** only one address.I successfully funded this address.But when I check **geth** console with **eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])** so its'value is 0.While I synced my node last 30 hours.I also firewall off my system So,Why it is happen ?? Please resolve this query as well as.

Comment: If `eth.blockNumber` is still 0 then your node has not synced, if `admin.peers` is empty then you have no peers and you will not sync no matter how much time you wait. You likely have a problem with your internet connectivity.

Comment: Hi Ismael thanks for answering.In my case eth.blockNumber is still 0 but when I run command **eth.syncing** It show starting block **807648** and current block **807648**.And **admin.peers** also show not empty.So,my question is why **eth.blockNumber** is 0 while admin.peers is not empty.

Comment: The command `eth.blockNumber` will return 0 until the node has finished syncing. If `eth.syncing` return something that is not false the node is syncing, if `admin.peers` is non-empty then you have some peers and the syncing should be able to finish. Remember geth requires a SSD and will not sync with a HDD.

Comment: Hi Ismael,Thanks for answering.Is it any alternative of **geth**.Because I am using HDD.And you say **geth** require SDD.

Comment: You should able to run a light node `geth --syncmode light`

Comment: I am trying to sync data with this command.But It can't working.

Comment: Other option is to use a public node like infura.

Comment: Hi Ismael,Thanks a lot, when I connect geth node to test network  with "**--fast and --cache=2048**" parameters.So my node is sync is after 8 hours.And I successfully deploy smart contract on test network(rinkeby). But one question in my mind, **how my node is sync with funded block number??**.

Comment: It is better to edit your question to add more details.